# qtranslator not supporting hindi fonts?

Tags: php, wordpress, webfonts

I have installed **qtranslator** plugin and included Hindi language and also added **hi_IN.mo** file in language folder of **qtranslator** plugin. But when I create content in Hindi so its not supporting Hindi fonts like **kruti 010**, etc.

If it supports such fonts then what I have to do for that?

If it does not supports then what can I do to make it support my fonts?

Working on blog post to put contents in English and hindi. There are some texts from hindi fonts which are not supported in that content box for blog, content are originally written in **Kruti Dev** font.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does the result look like exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might solve your Problem:**

Actually you need to convert your page content from "Kruti Dev" to "UniCode" font which is recognized by the all major translator's Like

Goggle Translator, Qtranslator etc..

So for doing this translation you need just visit on an on-line converter tool :

[Online "Kruti Dev" to "UniCode" converter](http://www.infowebservices.in/hindi/)

And Post your text in given text field and convert that into UniCode

Here You can also upload your doc file, if your page size is too long.

Now you will get converted text content that you can use in your WP site page.

Happy Coding!!!